# Нагрузочное тестирование на 10000 запросов

Tags: нагрузочное-тестирование

какие характеристики сервера требуются на сервисе Яндекс.Танк Compute Cloud для проверки работы сайта под нагрузкой в 10000 пользователей?

Comment: А что говорит поддержка сервиса?

Comment: характеристики сервера где будет крутится сайт?

Comment: @gbg Поддержка пока молчит.

Comment: @KoVadim А зачем характеристики сервера подопытного? Мне нужно понять какой нужен сервер, чтобы рассчитать стоимость для нагрузочного тестирования в 10000 запросов.

Comment: ну может сервер умрет ещё при  100 пользователях. Для начала нужно понять, а какая нагрузка будет тестироваться. отдача статического index.html и запрос с перелопачиванием базы - два разных запроса. и тому, кто будет выполнять эти запросы скорее всего побоку, а вот кто их будет обрабатывать - нет

Comment: @KoVadim Xeon на 24 ядра в 48 потоков, частота 2,10 GHz, оперативной памяти 24 G.

Comment: может хватит, может нет. у меня был случай, когда 800 законных пользователей, обратившись одновременно уложили сервер побольше (там было 64гига памяти). просто они прислали очень большие xml.